# Overloading assignment operator for homemade Vector class

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

So, for an assignment I have created a class that simulates the Vector quality normally found in C++, and I am trying to overload the assignment operator (=), so that a deep copy can be carried out between two "vectors", but I keep running into issues. I realize my code is somewhat half-baked, but could anyone please help me?

```
//stdafx.h
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Vector.h
class Vector
{

double* arr;  // pointer to the first element of this vector
int cap; // number of elements arr can hold (i.e. size of underlying array)
int sz;// size of this vector


       // The increase_capacity function
       // Purpose: Dincrease capacity of vector
       // Parameters: new capacity of vecoter
       // Returns: none
void increase_capacity(int new_cap)
{
    // Increases the capacity of the underlying array to be sz. If sz
    // is smaller than the current capacity then nothing is done.
    double* new_arr = new double[new_cap];   // allocate a new array

    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    { // copy old vector into new one
        new_arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    cap = new_cap;//set new capacity of vector

    delete[] arr;//delete old vector from memory
    arr = new_arr;//set old vector to new vector
}

public:
    // The non-parameterized constructer
    // Purpose: create an empty vector with capacity of 2 and size of 0
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: vector
    Vector();

    // The Parameterized Constructer
    // Purpose: create an empty vector with capacity of n and size of 0
    // Parameters: int n
    // Returns: vector
    Vector(int n);

    // The size function
    // Purpose: get current size of vector
    // Parameters: 
    // Returns: vector size as an int
    int size() const; 

    // The push_back function
    // Purpose: push back values into vector
    // Parameters: int n
    // Returns: none
    void push_back(int n); 

    // The capacity function
    // Purpose: get current capacity of vector
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: capacity of vector as a double
    double capacity();

    // The at function
    // Purpose: get value stored in vector at index n
    // Parameters: int n
    // Returns: value stored at index n as a double
    double at(int n) const;

    // The clear function
    // Purpose: clear and reset vector to an empty vector with capacity of n and size of 0
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    void clear();

    const Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector & rho);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& vctr);//allows overloaded insertion operator

    // The destructor
    // Purpose: clears data on heap and prevents memory leaks
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    ~Vector();

};

//Vector.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Vector.h"

//const int to hold value of 2
const int DUO = 2;
//const int to hold badIdex throw value
const int BAD = -6;


// The non-parameterized constructer
// Purpose: create an empty vector with capacity of 2 and size of 0
// Parameters: none
// Returns: vector
Vector::Vector()
{
    arr = new double[DUO];
    cap = 2;
    sz = 0;
}

// The Parameterized Constructer
// Purpose: create an empty vector with capacity of n and size of 0
// Parameters: int n
// Returns: vector
Vector::Vector(int n)
{
    arr = new double[n];
    cap = n;
    sz = 0;
}

// The destructor
// Purpose: clears data on heap and prevents memory leaks
// Parameters: none
// Returns: none
Vector::~Vector()
{       
    delete[] arr;
}

// The size function
// Purpose: get current size of vector
// Parameters: 
// Returns: vector size as an int
int  Vector::size() const
{
    return sz;
}

// The push_back function
// Purpose: push back values into vector
// Parameters: int n
// Returns: none
void Vector::push_back(int n)
{
    if (sz >= cap) increase_capacity(DUO * cap);
    arr[sz] = n;
    ++sz;
}

// The capacity function
// Purpose: get current capacity of vector
// Parameters: none
// Returns: capacity of vector as a double
double  Vector::capacity()
{
    return cap;
}

// The at function
// Purpose: get value stored in vector at index n
// Parameters: int n
// Returns: value stored at index n as a double
double Vector::at(int n) const
{
    if (arr[n] >= 0)
    {
        return arr[n];
    }
    else
    {
        throw BAD;
    }
}

// The clear function
// Purpose: clear and reset vector to an empty vector with capacity of n and size of 0
// Parameters: none
// Returns: none
void Vector::clear()
{
    delete[] arr;
    arr = new double[DUO]; 
    cap = 2;
    sz = 0;
}

//Driver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Vector.cpp"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


// the printV function
// used to test the copy constructor
// parameter: a Vector object
void printV(Vector& v);


// The overloaded stream insertion function
//Purpose: allow cout to print objects
// Parameters: pointer to ostream object, pointer to Money object
// Returns: os object
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& vctr)
{

os << vctr;//allow printing of objects from Money class
return os;//return printed information
}

const Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector & rho)
{
// TODO: insert return statement here
// test for self assignment
if (this == &rho)
    return *this;
sz = rho.size;
// clean up array in left hand object (this)
delete[] this;

// create a new array big enough to hold right hand object's data
lho.size = rho.size;
this->lho = new char[sz];

// copy the data
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    this->lho[i] = rho.lho[i];
}
// return this object
return *this;
}


int main( )
{
cout << "\nCreating a vector Sam of size 4.";
Vector sam(4);

cout << "\nPush 12 values into the vector.";
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    sam.push_back(i);

cout << "\nHere is sam: ";
cout << sam;
cout << "\n---------------\n";

cout << "\nCreating a vector Joe of size 4.";
Vector joe(4);
cout << "\nPush 6 values into the vector.";
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    joe.push_back(i * 3);

cout << "\nHere is joe: ";
cout << joe;
cout << "\n---------------\n";

cout << "\nTest the overloaded assignment operator \"joe = sam\": ";
joe = sam;

cout << "\nHere is sam: ";
cout << sam;
cout << "\n---------------\n";

cout << "\nHere is joe: ";
cout << joe;
cout << "\n---------------\n";

// pass a copy of sam by value
printV(sam);


cout << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void printV(Vector& v)
{
cout << "\n--------------------\n";
cout << "Printing a copy of a vector\n";
cout << v;
}
```

Comment: what exact issues are you running into?   Please ask a specific question -- stack overflow isn't for code reviews.

Comment: It seems that your post doesn't quite have enough information, like what are your issues?  A lot of people on SO are not going to want to sift through your entire code line by line so it might help if you can narrow down where you think the problem is in the future.

Comment: Error C2448 'printV': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition project4\driver.cpp 102 
Error (active) identifier "lho" is undefined Project4\driver.cpp 45 
Error (active) class "Vector" has no member "lho" Project4\driver.cpp 46 
Error (active) class "Vector" has no member "lho" Project4\driver.cpp 51 
Error (active) class "Vector" has no member "lho" Project4\driver.cpp 51 
Error C2065 'Vector': undeclared identifier   project4\driver.cpp 20 
Error C2065  'v': undeclared identifier   project4\driver.cpp 20

Comment: There are many errors, but that main issues seem to resolve around the operator= overload function.

Comment: @jonthie put the error message in the question and format it properly.  You can edit your question -- don't put it in a comment.  You also need to post properly formatted code in your question.

Comment: @xaxxon, There are at least 30 errors, way over the limit of characters to post. Did I miss some code with the 4 space indent?

Comment: @jonthie check out Vector::operator= but there is missing indentation all over.

Comment: `delete[] this`? Harakiri? Shouldn't it be `delete[] this->lho`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error (active)  identifier "lho" is undefined
```

This error is caused because you are using the variable `lho` which is not defined anywhere. You need to either define it or use a different variable.

Comment: I tried defining it 
    const Vector& iho Vector::operator=(const Vector& rho)
but this didn't resolve anything and ended up causing more problems...

Comment: Try replacing `lho` with `this`

Comment: you mean replacing it with const Vector& this Vector::operator=(const Vector& rho) ?

Comment: The declaration should probably be `Vector& operator=(const Vector& rho)`. Inside the function, you can use `this` as a variable (it is the only variable implicitly declared, it refers to the "current" object which in this case is the left hand side of the operator).